# NSRangeException when change dataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, datasource

I have `UITableView` which dataSource change by selecting `UISegmentControl's` segment. It has only 2 segments and for both states I load data asynchronously first time into 2 different arrays "firstTypeNotificationsArray" and "secondTypeNotificationsArray". The main array is dataSource for `UITableVIew` which has data from one of arrays each time and it named "allNotificationsArray".

**Change main dataSource data method**

```
-(void)changeNotificationsByType:(BOOL)firstType{
    [allNotificationsArray removeAllObjects];
    if(firstType){
        [allNotificationsArray addObjectsFromArray:firstTypeNotificationsArray];
    } else {
        [allNotificationsArray addObjectsFromArray:secondTypeNotificationsArray];
    }

    [notificationsTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] 
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Before call method `changeNotificationsByType` I check my arrays count to be !=0 but I get an `NSRangeException` after calling.

**numberOfRowsInSection method**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return allNotificationsArray.count; 
}
```

I tried to call `reloadSections` in main thread with `dispatch_async` but it didn't help. I've also tried to do `reloadData` instead and no result.

**Here is a crash log:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 60 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x265ec87b 0x3832adff 0x26502633 0xfcb9f 0x196879 0x3ee4a5 0x1a9dd17 0x1a9dd03 0x1aa27c9 0x265af555 0x265ada4f 0x26500129 0x264fff1d 0x2fac7af9 0x2a9889bd 0x10cc6d 0x38a78873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This crash raise after switching `UISegmentControl` and calling `changeNotificationsByType` respectively. All arrays are not empty at this moment and I can't understand why my app is crashing.

Comment: Plz log the count of array and see what is it giving? and log the count of the array when you switch the segments. Check if that is the same number of not.
And Why not reload the whole tableview? why only sections?

Comment: Set a breakpoint for all exceptions if you don't already have one.  When the program stops, you'll see exactly which line is causing the problem.  Then you can use the debugger console to print out the values of your array at that time.  (You say "not empty" and that's true; `[0 .. 0]` suggests there's one element in the array.)

Comment: I checked count of all arrays with breakpoints and everything seems to be ok. I reload only sections because of animations :) I don't know any other way to reload whole table with animations

Comment: Again, set an exception breakpoint.  If you don't see anything obvious when it stops, add the stack trace **with symbols** to your question and maybe someone will find a clue.